# Trapezoid proof

Tags: geometry

A trapezoid has diagonal from top left to lower right. The median is crossed by the diagonal. The length of the left part of the median is $x$, the length of the right part is $4.2$. The length of the bottom (longer) base is 12 and the length of the top base has been shown to be $2x-3.6$. **Edit:** The diagonal is bisected by the median.

How do I find $x$?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: We got to the part where the top base is $2x-3.6$. The problem actually calls that $y$ and asks us to find $x$ and $y$. We are at a loss for how to find $x$.

To get the value of $y$ (the top base), we used the fact that the median segment is half the sum of the other two segments, so that $2(x+4.2)=12+y$, then solved for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the median be $PQ, P \in AD, Q \in BC$ and  $PQ \bigcap BD=T$. Using Thales's Theorem for $\triangle ABD$ and the line $PT$ gives:

$$\frac{x}{12}=\frac{DT}{BD}$$

Thales's theorem for $\triangle BCD$ and $QT$:

$$\frac{4.2}{2x-3.6}=\frac{BT}{BD}$$

Now note that the $2$ fractions on the right sum up to $1$ and you can solve for $x$

Comment: Easier finish after the first equation is to recall that $DB$ is twice $DT$.